# parse string contains '"' retrieved from mysql to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I create a JSON object and store it to mysql then retrieve it again and parse it, when i stringify the JSON object it put the properties between "" when i try to parse the retrieved string i get unexpected end of input, this is the code

```
for(var i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
        var o=new Object();
        var id=objects[i].userData.id;
        var name=objects[i].name;
        o.id=id;
        o.x=objects[i].position.x;
        o.y=objects[i].position.y;
        o.z=objects[i].position.z;
        o.r=objects[i].rotation.z;
        resources[name]=o;
}
```

i insert `JSON.stringify(resources)` to mysql, the inserted string like `{"animalsherd0":{"id":"11","x":"4.7","y":"19.6","z":"18.8","r":0},"oasis1":{"id":"19","x":"-11.3","y":"19.6","z":"18.8","r":0},"corn2":{"id":"24","x":"-5.6","y":"19.6","z":"5.0","r":0}}`

the retrieved string stored in a variable so how can i parse this string?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** `jQuery.parseJSON`

```js
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"animalsherd0":{"id":"11","x":"4.7","y":"19.6","z":"18.8","r":0},"oasis1":{"id":"19","x":"-11.3","y":"19.6","z":"18.8","r":0},"corn2":{"id":"24","x":"-5.6","y":"19.6","z":"5.0","r":0}}');
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```